How to expand Scaffold's content to top bar in Jectpack Compose
I want to expand Material3 Scaffold's content to TopBar, but the top bar should not be overlap with sticky TabRow header from content body when scrolling down
Currently LazyColumn has top padding 0.dp, so the LazyColumn will expand to TopBar. When scrolling down LazyColumn, the TabRow will be at top of screen not below TopBar
Kotlin Code:
@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class, ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun ProfileScreen() {
    var selectedTabIndex by remember { mutableIntStateOf(0) }
    val tabTitles = listOf("About", "Moments")

    Scaffold(
        topBar = {
            TopAppBar(
                title = {},
                navigationIcon = {
                    IconButton(onClick = { }) {
                        Icon(
                            imageVector = Icons.Filled.ArrowBack,
                            contentDescription = "Back"
                        )
                    }
                },
                colors = topAppBarColors(
                    containerColor = Color.Transparent,
                    scrolledContainerColor = Color.Transparent
                ),
                scrollBehavior = TopAppBarDefaults.exitUntilCollapsedScrollBehavior()
            )

        },
        bottomBar = {
            Divider(modifier = Modifier.clip(RoundedCornerShape(20.dp)))
            Button(
                onClick = {}, modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(20.dp)
            ) {
                Text("Edit profile")
            }
        }
    ) { paddingValue ->
        LazyColumn(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .padding(
                    top = 0.dp,
                    bottom = paddingValue.calculateBottomPadding()
                )
                .background(onBackgroundDark)
        ) {
            item {
                HeaderBackground()
            }

            item {
                ProfileUserSection()
            }

            stickyHeader {
                ScrollableTabRow(
                    selectedTabIndex = selectedTabIndex,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .padding(10.dp, 0.dp, 10.dp, 0.dp)
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .clip(RoundedCornerShape(20.dp, 20.dp, 0.dp, 0.dp)),
                    edgePadding = 0.dp,
                    divider = {}
                ) {
                    tabTitles.forEachIndexed { index, title ->
                        Tab(selected = selectedTabIndex == index,
                            onClick = { selectedTabIndex = index },
                            text = { Text(title) })
                    }
                }
            }

            item {
                when (selectedTabIndex) {
                    0 -> TabAbout()
                    1 -> TabMoments()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}




I didn't quite understand what you are trying to achieve. Can you try to provide a better description, maybe with help of a translator?

Are you referring to the bottom sheet overlapping with the topBar? If so, you can resolve this by adding the modifier .navigationBarsPadding(). However, if this isn't the issue, could you please provide more details for a clearer understanding?

@AshutoshWahane the TabRow is warpped in StickyHeader, it will overlap with top bar when scrolling down, like image 1
